# Suppose R and S are relations $\subseteq A\times B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose R and S are relations $\subseteq A\times B$

a) Show that $R\cap S$ is also a relation $\subseteq A\times B$

b) Show $(A\times B)\setminus R$ is also a rlation $\subseteq A\times B$.

Do I have to show that $R \times S \subseteq A\times B$

I don't even know where to begin. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since a relation from $A$ to $B$ is defined as a subset of $A \times B$, indeed, you just need to show that the relevant sets are subsets of $A \times B$.

Comment: Do you know what $A \times B$ means?  And what would it mean for R to be a subset of that?  Start with the definitions ...

Comment: I know both R and S are subset of $A \times B$. So, I guess I will start with a pair indicating that $(a,b) \in R$ and $(a,b) \in S$?

Comment: In other words, I know I have to show that aRb and aRs.

Comment: I also know that R and S are subset of each other, right?

Comment: @Lily  given that $R \subseteq A \times B$, you know that $R$ is a set of pairs $(a,b)$ where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ ... but there may be any number of those pairs.  Same for $S$ of course.  So: in terms of those pairs, what is the intersection $R \cap S$?

Comment: @Lily And no, you don't know that $R$ and $S$ are subsets of each other .. the problem says nothing about how $R$ and $S$ are related to each other.

Comment: So would the intersection of R and S still be (a,b)?

Comment: @Lily  It would be those pairs $(a,b)$ (and again, there may be multiple of them) that are both in $R$ and in $S$

Comment: @Lily I started an example in an Answer below ... maybe that's the easiest thing to wrap your mind around this. Can you answer the two questions at the end?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let's do an example:

$A = \{ 1,2 \}$

$B = \{ a,b \}$

$A \times B = \{ (a,b)|a \in A, b \in B\} = \{ (1,a), (1,b), (2,a), (2,b) \}$

Now suppose $R$ and $S$ are subsets of $A \times B$, e.g:

$R = \{ (1,a),(1,b),(2,a) \}$

$S = \{ (1,a),(2,a),(2,b) \}$

Can you tell me:

What is $R \cap S$?

What is $(A \times B) \setminus R$?

Once you have figures this out, do you see why it will always be true that $R \cap S \subseteq A \times B$ and that $(A \times B)\setminus R \subseteq A \times B$, no matter what $A$ and $B$ are?

Comment: $R\cap S= (1,a) and (2,a)$; $(A \times B)  \setminus B= (1, 2), (1, b), (2,b)$

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: @Lily Yes on the first. No on the second.  Please note: I asked for $(A \times B) \setminus R$, not $(A \times B) \setminus B$

Comment: My bad, I think it would be just (1,2), (2,b)

Comment: @Lily No ... $(1,2)$ is not in $A \times B$ ...

Comment: Now I feel stupid. (1,2) is an element in $A \times B $ in your $A \times B$ set.

Comment: @Lily Oh!! My mistake! ThT should have been $(1,a)$!  Remember, the first element should come from A. , and the second from B.  OK, so sorry about that, I'll fix that

Comment: OK, so now $(A \times B) \setminus R $ is just $\{ (2,b) \}$. now, do you see that $R \cap S \subseteq A \times B$? And why that will always be the case, no matter what A and B look like?  Same for $(A \times B) \setminus R$?

Comment: Yes. Thank you again for your help on understanding this.

Comment: To prove a), would I have to show that if $(a,b) \in A \times B $, then $(a,b) \in R $ and $(a,b) \in S$ since R and S are subset of $ A \times B $. Thus, $ (a,b) \in R \cap S$. Hence, $ R \cap S \subseteq A \times B $.

Comment: @Lily No, start with $(a,b) \in R \cap S$. That means $(a,b) \in R$, and hence $(a,b) \in A \times B$. Indeed, notice that $R \cap S \subseteq R$, and since $R \subseteq A \times B$, we get $R \cap S \subseteq A \times B$

Comment: Ok. I got it reversed.